# elementary OS 5.1.7 HERA Bluetooth not working (Software trouble)

Tags: release-hera, bluetooth

My Bluetooth used to work fine, and now it doesn't...
Trouble is the following :

- Turning on BT from icon located on top of the screen --> ICON stays "off" after hiding the menu BT isn't working of course.
- Turning on BT from settings --> just stays on "discovering..." forever, Bluetooth isn't working of course.

[image] [image]

I updated the system via app center and it worked for a day or two but then again it failed (and kept on failing to this day).

This is really bothering as I can't have sound on my laptop (I work in an open space)...

Any help will be appreciated !

Simon from France

Answer (score 0):

I have a kind of similar issue with Bluetooth, When I connect my wireless buds to via Bluetooth and after 5-10 min it automatically gets disconnected.To connect it back I have to again disconnect and reconnect it and It's so annoying.